# Magento 2.1 Default Install Menu Issue (Google Chrome)

Tags: magento2

I have a default install on Magento 2.1 using DevBox.

However when loading up the frontpage the menu looks broken (has jquery ui styles applied )
[image]

Now I have not applied any stylesheets as it is a default install and as I read jQuery UI styles are not applied to magento due to this issue.
[image]

does anyone know how to address this issue?

Comment: Solved, it was a plugin causing the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be the standard magento luma theme it looks like it may be getting overwritten by a 3rd party extension, have you got any installed.